# I want to hide an element when a li becomes active on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

I want to hide a particular element when the contact section becomes active on SCROLL else they should be visible.
How can I do it using Jquery.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navmenu">       
    <li data-menuanchor="home" class="active">
        <a href="#home"><span>HOME</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="page">
        <a href="#page"><span>ABOUT US</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="gallery">
        <a href="#gallery"><span>PROJECTS</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="aboutus">
        <a href="#aboutus"><span>VIDEO</span></a>
    </li>
    <li data-menuanchor="contact" class="cont">
        <a href="#contact"><span>CONTACT</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What element do you wan't to hide?

Comment: <h1>Address</h1> I want to hide this only in contact section.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you want to hide the projects section when the contact section becomes active. Add a class "proj" to the project's `<li>`.

$(function() {

```
$(".cont").click(function() {

  $(".proj").css("display","none");

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".navmenu li").click(function(){
    if($(".cont").is(":focus"){
      $(".particular element").hide();
    }
    else{
      $(".particular element").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this also :

https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/8jdoLjnq/

```
jQuery(".nav li a").click(function(){
    jQuery(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    var parentLi = jQuery(this).parent('li');
    parentLi.addClass('active');
    if(parentLi.data('menuanchor') == 'contact'){
        jQuery("#element").hide();
    }else{
        jQuery("#element").show();
    }
})
```

**Update :** 
You can achieve that by handling scroll event. Something like this : 
https://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/8jdoLjnq/1/

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    if (jQuery(".cont").hasClass('active')){
        jQuery("#element").hide();
    }else{
        jQuery("#element").show();
    }
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to make an action when the li becomes active? what's the code for that?

Comment: If you check the fiddle, I added code for making `li` active on scroll for understanding. I am not getting what is not working.

Comment: Yeah but you made a fixed height like 100, after that only the li is getting active. I want the element to be hide whenever the scroll reaches the contact section

Comment: 100 is just to make it happen for understanding and making `li` active on scroll is a different question and nothing to do with these logic.

Comment: This is what you are looking for : [https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)